# fourier transform gaussian filter error

Tags: c++, opencv, fft

I'm new to openCV and I'm trying to filter an image using a gaussian filter in frequency domain. But there is a run time error 
"assertion failed (type == srcB.type() && srcA.size() == srcB.size()) in cv::mulSpectrum"
I know it is caused by the return type of my filter, the type doesn't match and I don't know how to make it right

here is the filter function (my guess is the return value from this function is wrong):

```
cv::Mat createGaussianHighPassFilter(cv::Size size, double cutoffInPixels){

Mat ghpf(size, CV_64F);

cv::Point center(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

for(int u = 0; u < ghpf.rows; u++)
{
    for(int v = 0; v < ghpf.cols; v++)
    {
        ghpf.at<double>(u, v) = gaussianCoeff(u - center.x, v - center.y, cutoffInPixels); //kernel utk gaussian filter yg 128x128
    }
}

return ghpf;
```

}

and this is the main function:

```
Mat mask = createGaussianHighPassFilter(complexI.size(),16);
shift(mask); 
Mat AX[] = {Mat::zeros(complexI.size(), CV_32F), Mat::zeros(complexI.size(), CV_32F)};
Mat kernel_spec;
AX[0] = mask; // real
AX[1] = mask; // imaginar
  merge(AX, 2, kernel_spec);

cout<<complexI.type()<<endl<<kernel_spec.type(); //the result is 13 and 14, the type doesn't match

mulSpectrums(complexI, kernel_spec, complexI, DFT_ROWS); // only DFT_ROWS accepted

updateMag(complexI);        // show spectrum
updateResult(complexI);     // do inverse transform
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course they don't match. You are initializing `kernel_spec` as `CV_32` but `complexI` is `CV_64`. Do a `Mat::convertTo()` and it should work.

HTH